# Pandas - float object has no attribute ix

Tags: python, pandas

This is my code:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(sing.ix[:-10], y.ix[:-10].T.corr(), test_size=0.2)
```

but I get this error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-32ea47dd4970> in <module>()
      1 # Split data into train and test leaving last ten (10) rows for the final evaluation
----> 2 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(sing.ix[:-10], y.ix[:-10].T.corr(), test_size=0.2)

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'ix'
```

Can someone explain how to fix it ? Thanks so much!

Comment: It looks like you're expecting a pandas DataFrame but got a float instead

Comment: `sing` and/or `y` is a float. Revisit the creation of those variables to make sure they are what you expect them to be.

Comment: Thanks, but what should I convert the float objects into?

Answer (score 1):

try typing:

```
print(type(sing)) # This will output object type of variable.
print(type(y))
```

and verify they're both DataFrame Objects.

Also to find methods pertaining to object types try typing:

```
# This will print a list of defined methods according to object type.
print(dir(sing))
```

or

```
# Displays documentation according to object/class
help(object type) # Ex. pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Comment: This is what I get: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'><type 'float'> so y is the float object...

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the sklearn library, so as far as what you're trying to accomplish, I'm of no use. Here is some documentation in relation to the method train_test_split() http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html. Although, you're unable to use the attribute ix  with a object type of float.